# Javascript function not being called from html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a javascript file that I loaded onto the page when it first runs that have several functions. Anyway, I'm trying to call on of those functions from the html page but it's not being called at all. I don't understand why. Here is what I have done.

Html part

```
<?php /* SCRIPT AREA START */ ob_start(); ?>
<script src="<?php ECHO SITE_ROOT; ?>assets/js/client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        client.displayMessage();

    });
</script>
<?php /* SCRIPT AREA END */ $data["scripts"] = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

This is the javascript part

```
var client = (function(){
...
var displayMessage = function(){
alert("Hello");
//stage.showErrorModal("Hello people", "Yeah");
},
....
}
```

EDIT:

```
var client = (function(){

    var socket, connected = false, typingArray = Array(), callWaitting, calling, callSound = null, onlineFriends = Array();

    init = function() {
        initializeSocketConnection();
    },

    initializeSocketConnection = function(){
        socket = io.connect(window.config.socket_server);


        socket.on('connect', onSocketConnect);
        socket.on('ready', onSocketReady);
        socket.on('inbox', sentMobileEvent);
    },
    onSocketConnect = function(){
        connected = true;
    },

    onSocketReady = function(){
        socket.emit('login', window.config.username, window.config.session_id, window.config.user_id, onLoginResponse);
    },
displayMessage = function(){
    alert("Hello");
    //stage.showErrorModal("Hello people", "Yeah");
    },
inbox=function(user_id){
    socket.emit("inbox", user_id);
    };

return {
        init: init,
        displayMessage: displayMessage,

    }

})();

client.init();
```

Comment: here `displayMessage` is not a property of `client` object, it is a private variable inside the function

Comment: We need to have some more info about the `client` function to give a proper solution

Comment: @ArunPJohny Like the whole function?

Comment: yes... we need to know what is returned from the function etc

Comment: it looks fine.... can you check the browser console to see whether there are any errors

Answer (score 0):

The `ob_get_clean()` function on the last line of PHP code will:

- [Get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)

Hence, everything in-between `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` will be stored in `$data["scripts"]` and **cleared** which means nothing will be sent to the browser.

Adding the following line after `ob_get_clean()` will send the buffered-and-cleared contents to the browser:

```
 <?
 echo $data["scripts"];
 ?>
```

However, if your intention is to display ***and*** make a back up of `<SCRIPT>` contents at the same time, you can use  `ob_get_contents()` instead.

**EDIT:**

Now with the full JavaScript source provided, I found some syntactic errors.

Some of your functions end with `,` which should be `;`.

The `init` function, for example (and other functions), could be fixed like this:

```
init = function() {
    initializeSocketConnection();
}; // ends with ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change `var displayMessage` to `this.displayMessage`, and try.

```
var client = (function(){
...
this.displayMessage = function(){
alert("Hello");
//stage.showErrorModal("Hello people", "Yeah");
},
....
}
```

and make it sure client is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

when you use client.displayMessage(),you have to make sure two things:
1.client is a Object or Array.
2.client has a property named displayMessage,and it's a function.
Obviously,"var displayMessage" means statement a variable in the function,not property.
so "client.displayMessage is undefined"